# Finding extreme value

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

It is given:

$f\left(x,y\right)=-7x^{2}-5xy+4y^{2}   $ and I should find x coordinate of the extreme value with condition $x-4y=4$.

I think I know how to do this, but my solution is not the correct. I hope someone can tell me where is my mistake.

**What I did:**

From condition I got $y=\frac{x}{4}-1 $. I put that in my function and got this: $-8x^{2}+3x+4=0 $.

I derivative it and got: -16x+3=0. So solution should be $\frac{3}{16} $. But it is not. What is my mistake?

Comment: What do you mean by "my solution is not the correct"? Does this come from a book or a test? If so, please add such information.

Comment: It is solution from online test.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
-7x^2-5xy+4y^2
&=-7x^2-5x\left(\frac x4-1\right)+4\left(\frac x4-1\right)^2\\
&=-8x^2+3x+4
\end{align}
$$
so that part is correct. Setting the derivative to $0$ gives
$$
-16x+3=0\implies x=\frac3{16}
$$
This looks correct.

Perhaps the solution is given as $\left(x,y\right)=\left(\frac3{16},-\frac{61}{64}\right)$. Note that the maximum value of the function under the given condition is $\frac{137}{32}$.

Comment: Solution is x=13. I dont know how..

Comment: Are you sure you read the question correctly? For x=13 and these conditions the value is much lower: -1309.

Comment: I think I did. They want from me x coordinate of extreme value. I tried other the same examples but never get correct.

Comment: Same answer comes from Lagrange multipliers.